# Как на изменение переменной вызвать определённый метод и перерендерить компонент

Tags: reactjs, mobx

У меня есть список товаров, которые заказал пользователь. Компонент который рендерит этот список, обращаясь к базе данных.

```
export class ItemsPanel extends React.Component {
    GetDataFromServer() {
        // код
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        GetDataFromServer();  // устанавливает state
    }

    public render() {
        return  <div> 
           здесь код выводит товары которые получены с сервера из this.state
        </div>
    }
}
```

У меня есть `LoginUserStore`, который хранит и отслеживает текущего пользователя

```
export class LoginUserStore {
    @observable UserInfo;
    @observable IsLogined;
}
```

Мне надо что бы при изменении `UserInfo` в `LoginUserStore`,
`ItemsPanel` заного вызвал `GetDataFromServer()` и перерендерился. Непойму как это можно сделать используя MobX.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение. Это `reaction` - https://mobx.js.org/refguide/reaction.html

Синтаксис такой:

```
const reaction2 = reaction(
    () => userStore.UserInfo, // то что отслеживаем
    userInfo => console.log("Name: "+userInfo.Name) // то что делаем при изменении
);
```